# Barbarian Throwing Weapons

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

After using the Level 14 Barbarian skill "Weapon Throw" in Diablo 3 with a Carver equipped, I presume that the weapon is magical? This is nothing like the "throwing weapons" from Diablo 2, in which, if I recall correctly, you had to equip the correct weapon type?

Comment: There are no throwing weapons in Diablo 3. The Weapon Throw skill lets you throw a melee weapon at some poor schmuck and have it inexplicably return to your hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All skills in diablo 3 (other than certain demon hunter skills that require bows) can be used while wielding any type of weapon, be it one handed, two handed or dual wielding.  The majority of the skills in the game have a % weapon damage associated with it and deals damage based on the damage as shown on the weapon (NOT the dps value on your character screen).

You'll notice that for weapon throw, no matter what you wield you'll always throw an axe (unless you use the throw hammer rune).